# Benchmark tools for the AMQP message broker LavinMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, lavinmq

I have been playing around with the AMQP message broker [LavinMQ](https://lavinmq.com/) for a while now. I want to do some benchmarking/test the thoughput before we go into production. Has anyone done some benchmarking on LavinMQ? If so - which tool have you used?

I have test with with RabbitMQ PerfTest, but I don't know if that is the right way to go.

Comment: PerfTest is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PerfTest, but its not going to be able to send messages fast enough. LavinMQ has the ability to handle a higher volume of messages than what PerfTest is capable of generating.

I would recommend using the tool that comes with LavinMQ, lavinmqperf.
Here is some documentation: https://lavinmq.com/documentation/lavinmqperf